# Reactive accumulation of data coming in bursts

Tags: reactive-programming, system.reactive, unirx

The problem: there is a stream of numeric values. Values are pushed in bursts so 100 values can come very close to each other (time-wise) say each 5-10 ms and then it possibly stops for a while, then can burst again.The idea is to show accumulated value (sum) of windows of at most length of 500 ms.

My first attempt was with Buffer(500ms) but this is causing constant pumping of events (every 500 ms) with the sum of 0 (as the accumulated buffer items os 0), it could be fixed with filtering by empty buffers but I would really like to avoid that entirely and only open the buffering after a value is actually pushed after a period of "silence".

Additional restrictions: the implementation is UniRx which does not contain all the Rx operators, notably Window (which I suspect could be useful in that case) so solution is limited to basic operators including Buffer.

Comment: Does `.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500.0))` do what you need?

Comment: @Enigmativity How do you mean? Throttle returns last value after silence period, how can I accumulate until Throttle fires?

Comment: You're right - I didn't read the question properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you just want the sum, using `Buffer` is overkill.
We can run a `Scan` or `Aggregation`.

```
  var burstSum =
    source
        .Scan(0, (acc, current) => acc + current)
        .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500))
        .Take(1)
        .Repeat();
```

This will start a stream which accumulates the sum until the stream has been idle for at least 500ms.

But if we want to emit at least every time bucket, we'll have to go a different path. We're making two assumptions:

1. The sum of time-intervals between elements should be equal to the time-interval between the first and last element.
2. `Throttle` will release the last value when the stream completes.

   ```
   source
       .TimeInterval()
       .Scan((acc, cur) => new TimeInterval<int>(acc.Value + cur.Value, acc.Interval + cur.Interval))
       .TakeWhile(acc => acc.Interval <= TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500))
       .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500))
       .Select(acc => acc.Value)
       .Take(1)
       .Repeat();
   ```

Comment: This is looking promising (no way to test atm) but the requirement is that the Sum() is for up to 500ms (it should be visualized every 500ms while burst lasts). So for example: if it bursts for 1,2 sec 3 sums are needed.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with UniRx. I have to refer to their wiki to see what's possible.

Comment: This should satisfy the time-bound, but not sure about UniRx behavior.

Comment: @Asti - careful with the `.Repeat` - your query is causing re-subscriptions to the `source` observable. Depending on how the `source` is constructed you can end up changing the character of the data. An obserlike `Observable.Generate(0, x => x < 10000, x => x + 1, x => rnd.NextDouble(), x => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3 * rnd.NextDouble()))` is guaranteed to produce a value with a gap no larger than `3` seconds - but with a `.Repeat` it might reset multiple times and the gap can be much larger.

Comment: @Asti - You should use the pattern `source.Publish(ss => ss.{stuff}.Repeat())` to avoid that.

Comment: @Enigmativity I knew you'd bring up the `Publish` thing, but there's no `Publish` overload like that available.

Comment: And it's very likely he has a hot observable, considering that he's getting burst events.

Comment: @Asti - Yes, there is a `.Publish` overload like that. It has the signature `IObservable<TResult> Publish<TSource, TResult>(this IObservable<TSource> source, Func<IObservable<TSource>, IObservable<TResult>> selector)` and it's always been in the library.

Comment: Where is it? I could only find the plain subscribe option. https://github.com/neuecc/UniRx/wiki/UniRx

Comment: @Asti - It's here: `System.Reactive.Linq.Observable.Publish`.

Comment: yes, there is no Publish() overload like that in UniRx, how does it work? Maybe it could be ported / impelmented